# Appending functions to a new list (I'm making a trivia game as a basis while I'm testing this out)

Tags: python, list, function, append

The basis of this is a trivia game that will call a random question (function), and I want to make it so it does not repeat. After I pull one of the function questions I want to add it to a list so it knows not to ask the question again.

Debugging with "print" is showing me nothing is getting appended to the new list. I then thought of trying to just write a unique integer identifier within each function/question to write to the new list. Can't figure out how to determine that within the main loop. Let me know if I can clarify anything better. PS. I'd like to stay away from the integer identifier idea if possible.

```
import random

a = 2

def question1():
    answerOne = str(input("What is the 2nd planet from the sun? "))
    if answerOne == ("Venus"):
        print("Correct!")
    elif answerOne != ("Venus"):
        print("Incorrect")
        print("The correct answer is Venus")

def question2():
    answerTwo = int(input("How many planets are there? "))
    if answerTwo == (8):
        print("Correct!")
    elif answerTwo != (8):
        print("Incorrect")
        print("The correct answer is 8")

def question3():
    answerThree = int(input("How many miles per sec does light travel? "))
    if answerThree == (186000):
        print("Correct!")
    elif answerThree != (186000):
        print("Incorrect")
        print("The correct answer is 186000")

appendedList = []

while a < 4:
    begin = int(input("Next question? 1 = Yes, 2 = No "))
    if begin == 1:
        my_list = [question1, question2, question3]
        que = (random.choice(my_list)())
        if que not in appendedList:
            print(appendedList)
            print(que)
            appendedList.append(que)
        elif que in appendedList:
            print(appendedList)
```

Comment: You set `que` to the return value of your question functions. They all return None. You could set `que` to the function itself and then optionally call it with `que()`.

Comment: In addition, as you don't want questions to repeat, you should only call the function when it is not inside the list **appendedList**. Thus you have to put the function call **que()** inside the if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

As @khelwood said in a comment, the problem is you're appending the return value of *calling* the question function instead of the question function itself. The fix is easy — don't do that, do this:

```
...

appendedList = []

while a < 4:
    begin = int(input("Next question? 1 = Yes, 2 = No "))
    if begin == 1:
        my_list = [question1, question2, question3]
        choice = random.choice(my_list)  # Get function.
        if choice not in appendedList:
            choice()  # Call function.
            appendedList.append(choice)
...
```

Answer (score -1):

you're basically calling the function and assigning it's return value to the variable **que** - which is **None**. Instead you should assign it to the variable and call it afterwards. I'll add the corrected version of the code below.

```
while a < 4:
    begin = int(input("Next question? 1 = Yes, 2 = No "))
    if begin == 1:
       my_list = [question1, question2, question3]
       que = random.choice(my_list)

       if que not in appendedList:
          print(appendedList)
          appendedList.append(que)
          que()
       elif que in appendedList:
          print(appendedList)
```

Comment: That makes so much sense, I feel like an idiot. Thank you for explaining that.

Comment: Doesn't that also mean that "print(que)" is redundant now with me calling "que()"?

Comment: @Justin **print(que)** prints out the function itself, thus if you would like to know what function was chosen by the random module, it makes sense. But of course, you should only log information which you actually need.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's because your functions returns nothing and que is empty.

If you want to return function you may be can do something like this:

```py
def function():
    # some useful staff
    return function # if return self func
    # or
    return another_function
```